# Riemann integrability implies following.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, show that $|\int_a^b f(x)dx| \le \int_a^b |f(x)|dx$.

Note: This is NOT a homework question; I'm missing this proof in my notes for some reason (either I missed class or lost note).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a Riemann sum belonging to a partition $a=x_0<\ldots <x_n=b$:
$$\left|\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm  dx\right|\approx \left|\sum_{k=1}^n f(\xi_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)\right|$$
$$\int_a^b\left|f(x)\right|\,\mathrm  dx\approx \sum_{k=1}^n \left|f(\xi_i)\right|(x_{i+1}-x_i)=\sum_{k=1}^n \left|f(\xi_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)\right|.$$
Then the claim follows form the triangle inequality for $|\cdot |$.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by the triangle inequality for $|\cdot|$?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$, $g$ is Riemann integrable and $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ then $$\int_a^b f(x)dx\le \int_a^b g(x)dx.$$ So $$-\int_a^b|f(x)|dx\le \int_a^bf(x)dx\le \int_a^b|f(x)|dx,$$ and we get desired result.